# JSP Getting variables from one file to another

Tags: jsp, jstl

! **NOOB ALERT** !

I'm not a coder and I don't know how this whole thing exactly works, but within our inside web based OS for data collection, we use .jsp files to print reports and such. The one file (*report1.jsp*) is generating more parameters (usable variables) than the other file (*report2.jsp*). I don't know where they're getting those variables from.

Is there a way to access those variables from *report1.jsp* and use them in *report2.jsp* ?

PS.
I don't have access to Servlets. Only the end of the stick (aka jsp files).

Answer (score 0):

You could put the variables into a different jsp and include them in both report1.jsp and repot2.jsp.

variables.jsp

```
<%
    String username = "john";
%>
```

report1.jsp

```
<%@ include file="variables.jsp" %>
```

report2.jsp

```
<%@ include file="variables.jsp" %>
```

You could also try to set a session attribute in report1.jsp.

```
<%
    String username = "john";
    request.getSession().setAttribute("username", username);
%>
```

And use the variable in report2.jsp

```
<%
    String username = (String)request.getSession().getAttribute("username");
%>
```